# Python requests error 404 on existing webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to access tumblr's images but whenever I try to make a get request I'm getting an error 404 although i can access the website in the browser

```
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}

r = requests.get("http://64.media.tumblr.com/673aaa6fd8714ff7cbd5ff21e3f19476/01106f992f82da57-52/s540x810/9cba083dbbbcdf4b18283085ef22d03d01f8d59d.png", headers=headers)
print(r)
```

output:

```
<Response [404]>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
headers = {
    "Host": "64.media.tumblr.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "If-None-Match": 'W/"41ee-5DDkMYZktzWx+HELCe1ttaTvrf0"',
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "TE": "Trailers",
    }

r = requests.get("https://64.media.tumblr.com/673aaa6fd8714ff7cbd5ff21e3f19476/01106f992f82da57-52/s540x810/9cba083dbbbcdf4b18283085ef22d03d01f8d59d.png", headers=headers)
print(r)
```